# How to add spring-security-oauth server to an existing web application with classic authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I have a web application with classic cookie based authentication. That is how it is configured:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/some/restricted/urls*").access("hasRole('admin')")
            .antMatchers("/some/public/urls").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('registered')");
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureAuthenticationManager(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Now I want to enable external apps to access some of my users data using OAuth2. First I added Authentication like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager auth;

    @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() {
        return new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        final ApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler approvalHandler = new ApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        approvalHandler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService());

        endpoints
            .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
            .authenticationManager(auth)
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .userApprovalHandler(approvalHandler)
            .pathMapping("/oauth/confirm_access", "/api/oauth2/confirm_access")
            .pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/api/oauth2/token")
            .pathMapping("/oauth/check_token", "/api/oauth2/check_token")
            .pathMapping("/oauth/token_key", "/api/oauth2/token_key")
            .pathMapping("/oauth/authorize", "/api/oauth2/authorize");
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work perfectly fine. My web app in general seems to work and I can get a code and exchange it for an access token. Just the access token by itself is rather useless so I want to add a service that requires a valid access token. To do so I added this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class Oauth2ResourcesConfigurationAdapter extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager auth;
    @Autowired
    private OAuthServerConfig oAuthServerConfig;

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources
            .authenticationManager(auth)
            .tokenStore(oAuthServerConfig.tokenStore());
    }
}
```

However this gets me an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer@6dd1c3ed to already built object
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.add(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:192)
```

I read the source debugged and google the best I could but I just cannot figure out what is happening here. The closest hint I found is [this ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/517), however it does not come with an explanation of the problem and I have been remarkably unsuccessful in writing my own configuration as suggested in the ticket, probably because I don't know what the problem is and thus what I need to change.

Comment: Could you post complete stacktrace? I've experienced the same error a few days ago and the root cause was at the top of the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime robsilvia gave an answer in the github ticket listed above. In short it says, that this method must be added to the `Oauth2ResourcesConfigurationAdapter`

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

However this caused my oauth configuration to interfere with my classic web app security configuration which did not work properly anymore. However I did find out about ["multiple HttpSecurity"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jc.html#multiple-httpsecurity) and thus I ultimatively solved the problem by using this variation:

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatcher(new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/path/to/oauth/endpoints/*"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/protected/resource")
        ))
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```